# DOM Elements don't load until I resize Chrome browser (Works perfectly in Safari)

Tags: dom

The innerHTML I'm inserting doesn't show up on the browser until I resize the window. Here's the site I'm having the problem on: http://www.granthpark.me/outside

```
<h1 id="mainz">
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c1ea49b3e06dc3b3/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json",   
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
      var weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
      console.log(weather);
      if (weather == "Patches of Fog" || weather == "Shallow Fog" || weather == "Partial Fog" || weather == "Overcast" || weather == "Clear" || weather == "Partly Cloudy" || weather == "Mostly Cloudy" || weather == "Scattered Clouds" || weather == "Light Mist" || weather == "Heavy Mist") { 
      document.getElementById("mainz").innerHTML = "The weather at Outside Lands is OKAY!";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("mainz").innerHTML = "The weather at Outside Lands sucks right now.";
      }
    }
      });
    });
    </script>
</h1>
<p id="weather" style="font-size:30px;">
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c1ea49b3e06dc3b3/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
      var weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather'];
      document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = "Current temperature in " + location + " is " + temp_f + "&#176" + "F" + " and it's " + weather.toLowerCase() + ".";
      }
      });
    });
    </script>
</p>
```

Here's my CSS in case: http://www.granthpark.me/assets/css/main.css

Comment: Can't repro on chrome v43. Also you may want to do a single request to the json and gather your callbacks in the same success function.

Comment: It's not loading for me, here's the actual site if it helps http://www.granthpark.me/outside

Comment: Ok, can repro on your site and strangely enough If I do update the inner text in the dev tools, it won't update until css is redrawn. Maybe something in your css prevents this.

Comment: I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: Huh I have no clue either. Awesome find and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange behaviour indeed.

It seems to come from your `#wrapper` stylesheet :

remove the `position:fixed` or replace it to `position:absolute` and it seems to work.

Don't clearly know why though, since your css is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Crome and Firefox, but if you don't find a better solution you could try adding this line `$(window).trigger('resize');` to the ajax success functions after modifying innerHTML.

Comment: Now that you provided the link I tried this and realized it did not solve the problem.